# Software to create nice presentations/infographics

Tags: effects, presentation

I need to find some software that will help me create a nice and user friendly presentation, like this one :

I prefere to use better effects and transition between objects but powerpoint needs lot of work to do that, and it is very hard to get it done with good precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would like to take a look at this free online presentation editor:

[Prezi.com](http://prezi.com)

It might not give you results as "fancy" as in your provided video sample but you might be satisfied by it's simplicity of constructing your presentations in a dynamic way. Here is some presentation [sample](http://prezi.com/sx2j5xrnniam/3d-backgrounds-freshwater-shortage/) to check it out if still wondering before signing up.

Answer (score 7):

A graphic like this would have most likely been made using **[Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html)**. The style of this graphic is a mix of Kinetic Typography and Infographics.

Googling around you can find tutorials on creating infographics and kinetic typographic videos. Though as a warning, generally creating a video like this takes a number of days for an experienced user.

Comment: i know about after effects and its capabilities, but it's more complicated and time consuming than PowerPoint.

Comment: thats the trade off for custom graphics I'm afraid :p

Answer (score 1):

Whether you do this in Powerpoint, Flash, or After Effects, it's still going to require a bit of prep work to get all the elements ready. I don't know what your skill level and experience is at this kind of thing, so please excuse me if I'm saying things you already know, but it may be best to carefully storyboard the entire thing then collect all the assets you need. This will go a LONG way towards simplifying the process in the long run.